# Ошибка malloc(): corrupted top size в программе на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, split

Пытался сделать программу в C++, которая бы разделила *char array* по пробелам, и сгенерировала массив со словами из строки. Но в определённом моменте возникает ошибка:
`malloc(): corrupted top size`

Долго пытался решить проблему, но не смог. Вот полный код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    char row[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua";

    const int n = sizeof(row);
    int words_n = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(row[i] == ' ') words_n++;
    }

    char **words = new char*[words_n];
    int words_cntr = 0, sym_cntr = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(row[i] == ' '){
            words[words_cntr] = new char[sym_cntr];
            for(int j = i - sym_cntr; j < i; j++){
                cout << row[j];
                words[words_cntr][j] = row[j];
            }
            cout << endl;
            words_cntr++;
            sym_cntr = 0;
        }
        else sym_cntr++;
    }

    delete[] words;

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка возникает после нескольких итераций в цикле, на строчке:
`words[words_cntr] = new char[sym_cntr];` При чём несколько слов добавляются в массив, и всё нормально, но потом что-то идёт не так...

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вперед в отладчик проверять значения переменных на каждой итерации. И еще количество вызовов `new` и количество вызовов `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокол первый, не очень принципиальный — вы выделяете

```
words[words_cntr] = new char[sym_cntr]
```

память без учета нулевого символа. Но так как вы не используете указатель на строку, это *пока* не так важно. Но станет очень важно при работе со строками.

А вот *куда* вы пишете — важно.

```
words[words_cntr][j] = row[j]
```

Обратите внимание — скажем, слово с 15 по 18 символ (образно) вы и пишете в выделенные несколько байт с 15 по 18 символ! Чему у вас равно `j` в `words[words_cntr][j]`?

Как исправить — сами разберетесь?

Кстати, а если вдруг у вас между словами будет по несколько пробелов — тогда как?

И еще — если вам годится просто массив указателей... не проще ли так? :)

```
int main(){
    char row[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua";

    const int n = sizeof(row);
    int words_n = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(row[i] == ' ') words_n++;
    }

    char **words = new char*[words_n];
    int counter = 0;
    words[counter++] = row;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(row[i] == ' ')
        {
            row[i] = 0;
            words[counter++] = row + i + 1;
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) cout << words[i] << endl;

    delete[] words;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне помогли, я разобрался. Просто я очень слаб в программировании, ещё и в выделении памяти и т.д.... Поэтому часто делаю такие ошибки.